# If we just change Tags why our questions appear all of sudden to everyone?

Tags: support

Its so embarrassing for me to see all my 6-7 qns at once place when I edited few tags. Any way to revert my edit?

Comment: No, when you edit even one full stop it’ll come on the main feed. And you can revert your edit but if you revert it, it’ll be another edit and will come back again on top of the screen with the old tags.

Comment: Are yaar  @Archit But thanks a lot for telling else I would make a mess lolz

Comment: @Archit Edit 3/4 of your most upvoted answers its a request pls
And you can get more upvotes also

Comment: The issue is such, almost everyone in the community is too lazy to vote. Again all my answers are long and they don’t have patience to read like my recent ones, so even if you edit it it doesn’t score anything. All of the recent ones had a shabby performance. For eg. Yesterday, The question got 6 votes but my accepted answer got 3. The only exception was: there was one chap called Abhiram Ekula who used keep editing his answer and therefore my top Mahabharata answer used to get votes, after a point people stopped voting, but this was one exception. Rest get 1-2 votes or 4-5 votes.

Comment: Common bhai do something please @Archit

Comment: There’s nothing!! Probably HSE can do something? Above every answer have this banner - please vote!!!!. Or in these huge answers have voting arrows even below, so people don’t scroll up to vote. Or even better a feedback thing - did you like the answer? And then if a person clicks Yes, it records a vote. If he clicks no, nothing happens. Downvotes people give easily so we’re not concerned there.

Comment: @Archit Fine..Thanks for your patience and helping me my dear friend

Comment: Only solution is not being embarrassed about it and continuing the good work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way for this. Every edit to a post bumps it to the front page, to prevent users from making malicious edits and nobody noticing it. This is true even for rollbacks (those can be malicious too under certain circumstances). I'm sure you meant no harm, but there's no way to undo this right now; just sit still and relax :)